# How do I conditionally add with boost MPL?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

I am trying to evaluate a bitset's value based on the type arguments provided. The function I have right now is this:

```
template <class Set, class PartialSet>
constexpr auto tupleBitset() {
    using type = 
        typename mpl::fold<
            PartialSet,
            mpl::integral_c<unsigned long long, 0>,
            mpl::eval_if<
                mpl::has_key<Set, mpl::_2>,
                mpl::plus<
                    mpl::_1, 
                    mpl::integral_c<unsigned long long, 1ull << getIndex<Set, mpl::_2>()>
                >,
                mpl::_1
            >
        >::type;
    return std::bitset<mpl::size<Set>::value>(type::value);
}
```

Basically the gist of the function's intent is to be able to create a bitset whose bits are created based off the intersection of `Set` and `PartialSet`, both of which are `mpl::set`s. The function `getIndex` is also provided:

```
template <class Set, class Index>
constexpr auto getIndex() {
    return mpl::distance<
            typename mpl::begin<Set>::type,
            typename mpl::find<Set, Index>::type
        >::type::value;
}
```

This approach doesn't seem to work, with the compile errors evaluating down to the following:

```
'value' is not a member of 'boost::mpl::same_as<U1> in 'not.hpp'
'C_': invalid template argument for 'boost::mpl::aux::not_impl', expected compile-time constant expression in not.hpp
```

Is it possible that the left shift is not a compile time constant?

---

It seems that the problem is with the call to `getIndex`, as the `mpl::_2` is not being substituted. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to force the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you pass the place_holder to the function `getIndex`.

You may transform your function in struct like that

```
template< typename Set, typename Index > struct getIndex
    : mpl::integral_c<unsigned long long, ( mpl::distance<
            typename mpl::begin<Set>::type,
            typename mpl::find<Set, Index>::type
        >::type::value )>
{
};

template <class Set, class PartialSet>
constexpr auto tupleBitset() {
    using type = 
        typename mpl::fold<
            PartialSet,
            mpl::integral_c<unsigned long long, 0>,
            mpl::eval_if<
                mpl::has_key<Set, mpl::_2>,
                mpl::plus<
                    mpl::_1, 
                    mpl::shift_left<mpl::integral_c<unsigned long long, 1ull>,
                                    getIndex<Set, mpl::_2>>
                >,
                mpl::_1
            >
        >::type;
    return std::bitset<mpl::size<Set>::value>(type::value);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c7ca4beac7592af)

Comment: This works but I am not sure why, can you explain why differing it to it's own struct makes the substitution work?